# One year and a half has passed? One year and a half have passed? has or have?

Tags: grammatical-number

Which is grammatical? has or have? or both of them?

I've already read some posts and assume that 'One year and a half' is plural. But I encountered "One year and a half has passed since we last met." 
When googling 'One year and a half has' and 'One year and a half have', I get similar numbers of results.

Comment: Google Search isn't a curated corpus of the English language, and the number of results that you get when you search for something is an estimate. Don't rely on that.

Comment: @userr2684291 Thank you for your advice:)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have missed the quotation marks in your Google search; the "has" variant yields 53,700 results for me, whereas the "have" variant gives just 78.

I would always pronounce it singularly. You don't have multiple years, you have one year plus a bit. Read it as:

> **One year** (and a half) **has** passed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have questions. 1) Then, how about 'Two years and a half'? According to your explanation, 'Two years and a half' should be followed by 'have', right? 2) Do you mean that 'One year and a half' is singular, not plural? 3) Is there any rule which I can refer to about this?

Comment: I already know that "One and a half years have passed." or "Two and a half years have passed" is right. My question is about "Two years and a half". How about this?